# UITabBarController added programmatically, but tab bar doesn't display

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I did not start from a `UIWindow` but from a `UIView` to add my `UITabBarController`.

I have an array of file names in `documentFileName` and hope to load them one by one in the subviews, each in one tab.

```
viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
(NSString *tempStr in documentFileName) {
Subview *subviewController = [[Subview alloc] initWithFileName:tempStr];
    [viewControllers addObject:subviewController];
}
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

In SubView.m:

```
- (id) initWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName {
    isiPhone = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:((isiPhone)?@"NFLSPromDressingsSubview_iPhone":@"NFLSPromDressingsSubview_iPad") bundle:nil])
    {
        currentFileName = fileName;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self loadDocuments];
    UITabBarItem *theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:[documentFileName indexOfObject:currentFileName]];
    self.tabBarItem = theItem;
}
```

However, the tab bar appears to be **white and empty**. Where did I made mistakes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure tabBar is initiated properly and in viewDidLoad method add tabBar to view `[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];`

Comment: I've already done that in parent view. In subview, I cannot find `tabBarController`.

Comment: @Abudullah Md. Zubair In parent view? <UITabBarController: 0x6b51f30>

Comment: @BenLu that means your tabBarController is created, but view controllers are set properly to tab bar controller. Make sure viewControllers array is not empty and set viewControllers array properly to tabBarController.viewControllers.